# How to get the 'no-verify' argument in pre-commit git hook

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I am developing some code quality checks using git pre commit hook. My idea is to send notification emails if some one skips the quality checks with this no-verify flag .I don't want to restrict the user from using  this flag on commit .In the pre commit hook script I want to read the no-verify argument of git commit and based on its presence ,I want to send emails.I am using VS2017 ,GIT,Azure Devops

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide code you have already tried - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. Using the `--no-verify` argument with `git commit` means that the `pre-commit` hook won't be executed at all.

As per the docs (the `githooks` manpage):

> This hook is invoked by git commit, and can be bypassed with the --no-verify option.

Comment: Thanks Is there any way in any of the git hooks to identify that the user has used this flag?

Comment: @Reshma not that I know of. No record is made of when/if the flag was used.

Comment: Thanks, How can I pass any custom parameter to the pre-commit hook then?

Answer (score 0):

You can skip a specific hook too, like this:

```
SKIP=flake8 git commit -m "foo"
```

Documentation link: https://pre-commit.com/#temporarily-disabling-hooks